# ZIF socket with 0.1" row spacing

Tags: connector, production-testing, zif

I am looking for a Zero Insertion Force (ZIF) socket with 0.1" between the two rows. The socket is to accept a DIP header like this:

[image]

So one side of the header would go into the ZIF socket, the other side is soldered to a PCB that is being tested.

The problem is that all the ZIF sockets I have found are similar to the green one below. They have 0.1" spacing between pins, but the two rows are at least 0.3" apart (they are all made for DIP package chips that are 0.3" across or more)

[image: ZIF socket]

Has anyone used or seen or have any ideas on a ZIF connector that would fit a DIP header/connector with 0.1" spacing between the two rows?

Comment: "...a PCB that is being tested." That usually screams out for pogo pins.

Comment: Usually ZIF sockets are used for programming ICs and hence the size. With the spacing specs you mentioned, I think you can go ahead with an FRC cable. I am not sure though whether this will serve your purpose.

Comment: Why not design your PCB with two single row headers separated by 0.3"?

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I agree, pogo pins would be great but were decided against due to cost and complexity. Unfortunately the board is already designed, so the header rows can't be spaced apart, I like that idea too though.

Comment: For now I guess I'll stick with a DIP socket that the header will plug into. It takes more force than I wanted and I was worried about how long the contacts will hold up, time will tell. I'll keep those ideas in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments ZIF sockets are not designed for 100 mil X 100 mil pitch because DIP chips aren't designed like that.

Your use is off-label. So you won't get a perfect solution, but you may look into using [a PGA burn-in socket](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/289-PRS17001-12/A316-ND/103008). It'll give you ZIF functionality with a 100 mil X 100 mil grid, though it will always be too large in one dimension for a >2 X 2 pin header.

[image]

Your alternatives are:

- Follow The Photon's advice and simply design your daughter board to have its programming header as 100 mil header rows separated by 300 mils.
- Use a single 100 mil header and tie the rows together on the ZIF socket.
- Use [pogo pins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin) like almost everyone else in industry and rightly suggested by  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.